# Batch insert pictures from folder to mysql table

Tags: mysql, perl, blob, batch-processing

I have a folder containing around 20.000 png images with size of around 500kb (barcodes) and i want to batch insert them into a mysql table.

I found this script but i could not get it to work properly

```
#! /bin/bash

dir=/folder/barcodes
ext=png
chmod a+r $dir/*.$ext
mysql -u root -p DBNAME <<eot
USE DBNAME;
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (name varchar(128), data mediumblob, PRIMARY KEY(ID));
USE DBNAME;
eot
ls -1 $dir/*.$ext | perl -e 'print "insert into t1(name,data) values ".join(",",map {chop;$f="\"".$_."\""; "($f,load_file($f))"} <>);' | mysql -u root -p DBNAME
```

my issues are:

- table does not get a primary key (i add one afterwords using phpmyadmin)
- the pictures are somehow not loades into the database (all values are NULL)

Comment: since you tagged this question with `perl` I would suggest the whole script would be better written entirely in Perl and using `DBD::mysql`

Comment: Well the problem is that i unfortunately cannot code in perl :/

Comment: Then do not use perl and use a langauge that you do know?